# business vs. businesses

Tags: single-word-requests

Does "businesses" only mean "companies"? How do you describe in saying "number or types of business model" that a single company is doing; e.g. ABC Trade & Co. is covering many "businesses" such as foodstaff trading, investmennt, financial services, logistics services, etc.

Answer (score 1):

"Business" can mean some sort of commercial activity as well as an entity that performs such an activity. So yes, you can use "businesses" to refer to the various activities of a single company. (You may also see the term "line of business" used for this.) Here are two of the definitions of "business" from *Webster's Third New International Dictionary, Unabridged*:

> a usually commercial or mercantile activity customarily engaged in as
>   a means of livelihood and typically involving some independence of
>   judgment and power of decision

and

> a commercial or industrial enterprise

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the sense, "business" is either countable or non countable: see [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/business). When it refers to a specific commercial enterprise or establishment (*what corresponds to your context*), business is countable and its plural is "businesses".

Answer (score 0):

The word "business" could be used as you have used it, to describe the various activities of a single company--"the ABC Trade & Company is in the food business and the investment business"--but this is pretty informal and colloquial.

In business jargon, there are three key terms that pertain: Sectors, industries, and markets.

A sector is a large segment of the economy. An entire national economy may include about a dozen sectors. Finance is a sector, entertainment is a sector, energy is a sector.

Each sector is made up of industries. The Finance sector includes such industries as banking, investment, and insurance.

Markets are the people that companies sell to. People who need banking services in Kowloon are a market. Investors in California real estate are another market.

Your example, ABC Trade & Co., has diversified. This means that it crosses the lines that separate sectors, industries, and/or markets. Companies that operate in several sectors include multinational conglomerates like General Electric, which began as a manufacturer of dynamos, electric motors, light bulbs, and sockets, and eventually got involved in healthcare, oil and gas, and financial services. Companies that operate in several industries include Walt Disney, which stays within the entertainment sector, but is an important player in cinema,  publishing, merchandising, theme parks, etc. Companies that serve several markets would include a car company that makes SUVs for families, pick-up trucks for construction workers, and luxury sedans for high-net-worth people.

As you can imagine, there a just a few very large companies that operate within multiple sectors, more that operate across industries, and many that serve or aim to serve multiple markets. The example you give suggests that ABC Trade & Co. operates in multiple sectors (foodstuffs, or agriculture, and finance), which certainly means it operates in multiple industries, and serves multiple markets as well.

A business model, BTW, is a design for the successful operation of a company, which includes the identification of revenue sources, a customer base, the products or services provided, details of financing, management of human resources, community relations, etc.